# Does a PHP process exit when you ctrl + c it from CLI?

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, background-process

I'm witnessing strange disk activity on one of our servers. The only thing I can think of is that during the day a lot of PHP processes were started from CLI in screen mode, like so:

```
php -f myprocess.php
```

As soon as I noticed the disk issue, I terminated these processes by attaching the screen, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> the process, and `exit`ing the screen. I would assume that this exits the PHP process. However, after an hour the disk activity is still very high and obstructively so. (I am no sysadmin so I cannot back-trace the activity.) I know that when you send an ajax request to a server and then abort that request (`jqxhr.abort()`), the server will still execute the request. I thought that maybe something similar could be going on when doing a "request" from CLI. The requests are done from home over SSH.

So, did I act correctly and should the processes have stoppped, or is it possible they will run until completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's construct a little test:

```
# File: infinite.php
<?php
while (true) { sleep(1); }
```

Run it, then monitor the process:

```
$ php infinite.php                        # screen one
$ watch -n 1 "ps aux | grep infinite.php" # watch the process (screen two)
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the process in screen one while you `watch` it from screen two.

#### Result:

The process dies. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> kills an active screen's PHP process.

---

It's possible that you may find the process continues to run if your client terminal simply closes due to a session timeout.

Comment: Clear and easy enough test case. Thanks!

Comment: One border-case addition: if your php script opens some process  (another php script, for example) in the background and disconnects using (popen, pclose) - you can't kill child process with ctrl+c and  `watch ps aux` will not see  it